# index of array that is passed

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, object-literal

How do I retrieve the index of the array that is passed? The solution I currently use is sending the index too, but that doesn't feel right.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NECNL/)

```
var obj = {arr: [{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 3, y: 4},{x: 5, y: 6}]};

function myFunction(myObj)
{
    alert(myObj); // 5
    // alert(the index of the array that is passed); // 2
}

myFunction(obj.arr[2].x);
```

Comment: You are not passing one of the objects in the array, but only a number?

Comment: Yeah, the answers below are on the money.  What specifically are you trying to do in context?

Comment: It would help a lot to know why it is you want to do this. It's a weird request, and my suspicion is that you're pursuing an errant course to your actual goal.

Comment: I'm trying to draw a line to the previous point.

Comment: Pass in the pair of points. It'd be much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.indexOf`  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NECNL/1/)

```
var obj = {arr: [{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 3, y: 4},{x: 5, y: 6}]};

function myFunction(myObj)
{
    alert(obj.arr.indexOf(myObj)); 
}

myFunction(obj.arr[2]);
```

Comment: This seems to work, even if the values are the same. But it doesn't add up with the other comments.

Comment: @wubbewubbewubbe that's because it's crazy to have your code do the extra work of *finding* something that's already been found elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

There's no real way to do what you're asking. JavaScript is purely call-by-value, which means that before a function call is made the arguments are *completely* evaluated. All that's left after the evaluation is the final value, and a copy of that is passed to the function.

You can of course write code that searches for a value in some relatively-global array, but that would be a waste of CPU cycles if you can instead simply pass the array index to the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, because the array or the index is not passed to the function, or even the object.

The array is read from the `arr` property of the object, then an object is read from the array, then the value is read from the `x` property of that object, and the function is called with that value.

Once inside the function, you can't tell that the value came from a property of an object, or that the object was stored in an array, or that the array was in turn a property in an object.